# Is it possible to parse this date-string to Date without modifying it?

Tags: java, validation, date, format, tostring

I've got the following date `Mon Feb 11 15:40:48 UTC+0100 2019`, is it possible to parse it into a `Date` object without modifying it? 
I've tried to parse it with the `SimpleDateFormat` class, but I couldn't figure out any working date-format.

Comment: Yes it's possible. But what do you mean by "without modifying it" ? First, a String is immutable in Java, so basicly you can't modify it.  Secondly, why you d'ont want to use a String derived from the original (like a substring fro example) ?

Comment: Why are you using `Date` instead of `OffsetDateTime` or something appropriate from the `java.time` package?

Comment: @vincrichaud i would like to avoid using regexp or substring, because the date-format in the data I get is not strictly defined, so I don't want to depend on a hardcoded string modification

Comment: What do you mean by "it's not strictly defined" ? The string does not always has this format ? How do you expect to parse it if it does not respect a format ? Or it does but you did not explain it ? You say you don't want to depend on hardcoded String modification, but SimpleDateFormat expect an hardcoded pattern...

Comment: By the way, you might educate the publisher of your data about [ISO 8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Java string to date conversion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4216745/java-string-to-date-conversion)